# Show logged In User details from my database to a label

Tags: c#, sql

I tried this query

```
SELECT Name 
FROM dbo.tbl_customer 
WHERE Name = @Name
```

but in the label it only shows the name of the table and in the form I have this code that when I debug my program and I log In the system and see the customer details in the label it only shows the table name as text.

The code of the form is

```
namespace Daniel_Boat_Dealer
{
    public partial class ShowCustomerDetailsFrm : Form
    {
        private Daniel_Boat_Dealer_DataBaseDataSet.tbl_CustomerDataTable customerDT;
        private Daniel_Boat_Dealer_DataBaseDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CustomerTableAdapter customerTA;
        private Customer customer;

        private void init()
        {
            customerDT = new Daniel_Boat_Dealer_DataBaseDataSet.tbl_CustomerDataTable();
            customerTA = new Daniel_Boat_Dealer_DataBaseDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CustomerTableAdapter();
            customer = new Customer();
        }

        public ShowCustomerDetailsFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            init();
        }

        private void ShowCustomerDetailsFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblCustomerIDNumber.Text = customerTA.GetDataByCustomerid(customer.IdNumber).ToString();
            lblCustomerName.Text = customerTA.GetDataByCustomerName(customer.Name).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh come on. Do you really expect anyone to be able to answer this "question"?

Comment: the label is empty an on the form load event I tried this code `code` lblCustomerName.Text = customerTA.GetDataByCustomerName(customer.Name).ToString(); `code`

Comment: Please edit your question to include any new information you have, such at code examples. The edit button is just below the question's tags.

Answer (score 3):

This is code you posted in the comments

```
lblCustomerName.Text = customerTA.GetDataByCustomerName(customer.Name).ToString();
```

I'm going to explain what your code is doing.

I have an object named customerTA, I'm going to call a method on this object to `GetDataByCustomerName` which I assume gets some data about a customer by their name, then you call a method on that object to turn it into a string (which may or may not be implemented). then you take this data and place it in a label's text property.

Why do you not just set it like this

```
lblCustomerName.Text = customer.Name;
```

---

Your SQL query is equally nonsensical

```
SELECT Name FROM dbo.tbl_Customer WHERE Name = @Name
```

The above procedure is getting a list of customer names which match a specific name. ie. in tbl_Customer you have 20 Jills and 15 Johns, if you run this procedure sending in the parameter `@Name = 'John'` you are going to get a list of strings like the following

> John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John, John

---

Try debugging the formload event, and hovering over the objects you have received from the database and see if they have properties which have the data you need.

*(And perhaps take a class on SQL and C# )*

Comment: I tried <code> lblCustomerName.Text = customer.Name; </code> and now the label is empty and the query is like that

Comment: @user3328666 Did customer.Name have a value to begin with? Because if not, then you cannot use it as a search parameter

Comment: No it's just a variable for another class that have a getter and setter

Comment: Then what do you expect to be happening when you run this code `customerTA.GetDataByCustomerName(customer.Name)` ? Could you also clarify what kind of object customerTA is?